# Close showOptionDialog after 5 seconds if not button is pressed in java

Tags: java, jframe, joptionpane

I have a showOptionDialog that ask if the user wants to delete something. I want to close the frame and not delete if nothing is press after 5 seconds. How can I achive this?

Here is my code:

```
         JFrame frame = new JFrame();
         frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
         Object[] options = {"OK"};
         int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,"Do you want to delete?","Title",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,options,options[0]);
         if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == n) {
             System.out.println("Delete");
         } else {
             System.out.println("Not Delete");
         }
```

Comment: roughly: create a `JOptionPane` using one of its constructors, create its dialog, start a thead to close that dialog after given time; and show the dialog.

Comment: You can use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.util.concurrent.Callable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

Comment: Don't use a Thread or ScheduledExecutorService. Swing components should be updated on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. So you should use a Swing Timer to schedule the event.

Comment: `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` doesn't return until the user closes it. Furthermore, it doesn't give you any reference to the dialog itself. In other words, I'm afraid this can't be done by means of an JOptionPane. You have to create your own window.

Comment: @RobertKock it sure can, just not with the `show...` methods

Comment: Closing a confirmation dialog after an arbitrary timeout, especially such a short timeout, is poor usability.  The reason there isn’t an easy API for doing this is that it’s a bad idea.  What makes you think the user has the dexterity to move the mouse to a button in five seconds?  What if the user has an important e-mail or alert at the moment the dialog is displayed?  A good rule of thumb for UIs is:  if it’s important enough to show to the user in the first place, it’s important enough to wait for the user’s response.

Answer (score 2):

Read the `JOptionPane API`. There is a section on `"Direct Use"` of the JOptionPane.

You will need to create the option pane and dialog manually. When you do this you will now have a reference to the dialog used by the option pane, which means you can dispose() of the dialog if it is still open.

So you will also need to create a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). When the timer fires you use `dialog.dispose()`.

You would need to start the Timer BEFORE the dialog is made visible.

Also, before you check the return value from the option pane you would want to stop the Timer, since you don't want the Timer to fire when the option pane is already closed.

So the basic logic (taken from the API) would be:

```
 JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(arguments);
 pane.set.Xxxx(...); // Configure
 JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);

 Timer timer = new Timer(5000, (e) -> dialog.dispose());
 timer.start();

 dialog.setVisible(true);
 timer.stop();
 ...
```

Edit:

> I change it to:

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(
    "Do you want to delete?",
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,
    null,
    options,
    options[0]);
```

I can see so many problems with the above statement:

1. Why are you using that constructor? Why are you passing so many null parameters? As I mentioned in my earlier comment there are simpler constructors to use.
2. Why are you specifying the "option type" before the "message type". Did you read the API? Can you show me a constructor where this is valid?

3 . Why are you using `JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE`? This is a question? Should you not be using `JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE`?

Did you even read the API like I suggested? You can't program if you don't read the API and understand what the different constructors and methods are.

> it returns an integer, but in this case where can I see it?

It may or may not return an integer depending on how the dialog was closed. If you click a button it will be an integer. If the Timer fires it will be a String.

Again, did you read the section from the API on `Direct Use`? It shows you how to get the value returned from the option pane and check it's value.

So once again I ask, did you read the API? Is there something about the code presented in the API that you don't understand. If so ask a specific question.

Comment: maybe a `timer.setRepeats(false);` ? but better than the old  naked Thread

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, the `timer.stop()` after the `dialog.show()` was designed to stop the timer whether the user closed the option pane or the timer disposed of the option pane. I don't know if there is a problem if the user closes the option pane and then the timer fires trying to close it again. I thought this would handle both cases to be safe.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont know what to put on arguments. I tried frame,"Do you want to delete?","Title",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,options,options[0] but it does not work

Comment: @danielgon, I have no idea what "not working" means. Does it complile? Does the dialog display? in any case: `read the JOptionPane API`.  Frist prove the basic concept of manually creating the option pane and dialog works. So why not start with the simplest constructor which is just a message?  Get that working and then try other constructors. One step at a time when learning a new concept.

Comment: If you need more help then post an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. So all you need is a JFrame with a button. When you click the button you display the option pane manually. Once that is working then you add the logic for the Timer. Once that works then you apply the solution to your real application.

Comment: @danielgon please check the documentation, I am pretty sure that the constructor does not accept a frame as first argument, it starts with the message (since the frame is given in `createDialog`)

Comment: okay, I change it to JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Do you want to delete?",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null,options,options[0]); and I get the dialog. But now how do I know if the button is clicked, the solution that I see around it´s like my code, it returns an integer, but in this case where can I see it? Thanks and sorry for my newbie questions

Comment: @danielgon, see edit. If there is something you still don't understand then update your question and post an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and test the code. The entire class will be about 10-15 lines of code. You already have the 7 basic lines of code needed to display the option pane. All you need is a few more lines of code to test the return value.

Comment: @danielgon don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.